# Run RSpec tasks in a specific order

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

I have a bunch of [RSpec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSpec) [Rake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_%28software%29) tasks defined that I'd like to run in a specific order when I run the entire suite of tests.

I've tried something like this:

```
task :run_in_order => [:one, :two, :three] do 
  puts "Run suite of tests"
end
```

And it runs the first test and then stops and doesn't run the rest of the tasks.

So if using Rake syntax it doesn't work. Is there a way to note task dependencies for RSpec Rake tasks?

Comment: Don't do it, it's a very bad practice because tests should be independent from each other

Comment: @luacassus i'm aware. I'm working on getting the something in place to not do it this way. However in the meantime, this is the way things are. So i'm looking for an answer other than 'don't do it.' Is this technically not possible with Rspec?

Comment: Maybe "don't do it" for actually finding out whether the tests pass, but if you're doing a run to produce a report of the specifications to discuss with a client then being able to produce the report in a meaningful order is pretty much essential.

Comment: If you have identified an ordering that fails and want to debug it, removing tests from the sequence to find a minimal failing example, this is essential. Unfortunately the accepted answer does not help.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Check this http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/01/04/rspec-28-is-released/

> –order rand We added an --order option with two supported values: rand
>   and default.
>
> rspec --order random (or rand) tells RSpec to run the groups in a
>   random order, and then run the examples within each group in random
>   order. We implemented it this way (rather than complete randomization
>   of every example) because we don’t want to re-run expensive
>   before(:all) hooks. A fair tradeoff, as the resulting randomization is
>   just as effective at exposing order-dependency bugs.
>
> When you use --order random, RSpec prints out the random number it
>   used to seed the randomizer. When you think you’ve found an
>   order-dependency bug, you can pass the seed along and the order will
>   remain consistent:
>
> --order rand:3455
>   --order default tells RSpec to load groups and examples as they are declared in each file

Basically you should order your tests in a spec file an then execute it with `--order default` option.
.