# rspec prints test not in default order

Tags: rspec, guard

I'm using guard, so it's not convinient for me to run specific test from command line so I guessed that rspec will run all test in order as they ordered in the file, but rspec runs test like in this example:

```
# ./spec/requests/projects_spec.rb:90:...
# ./spec/requests/projects_spec.rb:99:...
# ./spec/requests/projects_spec.rb:105:...
# ./spec/requests/projects_spec.rb:115:...
# ./spec/requests/projects_spec.rb:55:...
# ./spec/requests/projects_spec.rb:61:...
# ./spec/requests/projects_spec.rb:68:...
# ./spec/requests/projects_spec.rb:75:...
```

I've added to .rspec file the line `--order default` but it didn't change anything.

The vesrion of rspec is 2.11.0

How to make rspec to print tests as they are declared in file?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/10329020/205585 have a hunch that you don't have to say order in the file but when executing tests (or both are same? just trying to help, haven't used rspec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment out the line `config.order` in `spec_helper.rb` file.