# Run some RSpec files in default order

Tags: rspec, continuous-integration

I have our RSpec suites running in random order to ensure independence and robustness. However, there are a few cases when I want to run specs in order. I understand that I can just use `--order default` on the commandline, but I want to integrate this with CI. We use TDDium for CI, and I want to try to continue running in random on the CI server, but ensure that specific spec files run in order.

### Question

Is there any way to specify, on a file by file basis, that RSpec should run that file in default order? I see that there seems to be [some customized ordering strategy support merged into rspec-core](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/547), but that doesn't seem to be fully baked (and I'm not sure it supports `before :all`), I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.

### Discussion

And, since there is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321166/run-rspec-tasks-in-a-specific-order) about this that has downvoted because "specs should be independent" let me state my use-case to try to preemptively avoid the "you shouldn't do that" argument.

We have a complex model where various aspects of the system state changes over time. I have an analytics system that is watching that system to track the state change of various things over time. Thanks to the [Timecop gem](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop), I can go back in time, create a bunch of interacting models, then step through, say, 5 days and look at the system as seen by the analytics system, given known conditions, at each day. Specifically, to make sure that some calculations are correct given the assumption embedded in the system.

Now, I realize that I could have 5 separate describe blocks, each with goes through the process of setting up individual conditions for each of 5 days in history, but it made much more sense to me to step through time and watch the condition change while in that state. More efficient and more connected to what is actually happening in the system. I understand that I can mock various responses here and there, and we do that, but I'm interested in stepping through a "real-time" interaction between the base system and analytics system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should've just read the specs, and not the code from the [merged feature in the rspec core](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/commit/d79960bb6ebf63d005c2ed8d74f5a8f31bcc8e3b). It's pretty clear [given this spec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/d79960bb6ebf63d005c2ed8d74f5a8f31bcc8e3b/spec/command_line/order_spec.rb#L113).

Given a custom_ordered_spec.rb:

```
    RSpec.configure do |config|
      config.order_groups_and_examples do |list|
        list.sort_by { |item| item.description }
      end
    end

    describe 'group B' do
      specify('group B example D')  {}
      specify('group B example B')  {}
      specify('group B example A')  {}
      specify('group B example C')  {}
    end

    describe 'group A' do
      specify('group A example 1')  {}
    end
```

Both groups and examples within groups will be ordered by description. Furthermore, it looks like you can call `config.order_groups` and `config.order_examples`.

Here's my [blog post](http://mettadore.com/analysis/using-rspec-with-mixed-random-and-ordered-tests/) about it with a somewhat more detailed description.

Comment: The blog post link leads to a 404

Comment: @EricFrancis Thanks for that. Was moving hosts and forgot to actually do the import! D'oh.

Comment: And it is back to 404 again. Archive.org version: https://web.archive.org/web/20140805062301/http://mettadore.com/analysis/using-rspec-with-mixed-random-and-ordered-tests/

Answer (score 0):

Current (3.5) Rspec no longer has the order_groups_and_examples method. Instead you can [register an ordering](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.5/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration.html#register_ordering-instance_method):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.register_ordering :alphabetical do |list|
    list.sort_by { |item| item.description }
  end
end
RSpec.context "Test in alphabetic order", :order => :alphabetical  do
  describe 'group B' do
    specify('group B example D')  {}
    specify('group B example B')  {}
    specify('group B example A')  {}
    specify('group B example C')  {}
  end

  describe 'group A' do
    specify('group A example 1')  {}
  end
end
```