# How do I use --order option in Rspec to order files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, rspec-rails, rspec3

I want to run feature specs written in `rspec/capybara` in a fixed sequence as follows:

```
signup_spec.rb
login_spec.rb
project_creation_spec.rb
project_migration_spec.rb
```

The `--order` feature of [given here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-9/docs/command-line/order-new-in-rspec-core-2-8) says that

```
Use the --order option to tell RSpec how to order the files, groups, and
examples
```

How would I use .rspec file to mention pass my requirements ?

I have a shell script with test cases running in a sequence like:

```
rspec spec/features/signup_spec.rb
rspec spec/features/login_spec.rb
rspec spec/features/project_creation_spec.rb
rspec spec/features/project_migration_spec.rb
```

Comment: Can I ask you why you want to apply a fixed order? Specs should be able to run independently. In fact, newer versions of RSpec default to a random order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run RSpec tasks in a specific order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321166/run-rspec-tasks-in-a-specific-order)

Comment: I want to run specs in a specific order so as to populate data as close to user experience And being a client requirement, so I already know about how they should go and what rspec is doing for randomization but still does not answers the question.

Comment: @SpyrosMandekis Updated the question, it does not asks a specific question away from the question you referred.

Comment: I do not think that Rspec has such a feature built-in (somebody correct me), but I will completely agree with @SimoneCarletti, your tests should run independently.  You can use a background/let combination to set the state of your application for the tests that depend on previous ones.

Comment: While I understand the use of some examples run in specific order, I think your full features need to be written in a way to be independent of one another.  I'm guilty of testing CRUD operations in a specific order within a feature, but that feature spec should not collide with others.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I found this thread because I need the specs to be ordered for _rswag_. The generated swagger file changes on each run otherwise. While this is a bug in _rswag_, I still need to solve the issue somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The order option does not allow this. It allows switching between the default ordering (which is essentially that they are run in the order they are defined which in turns depends on file system ordering ) or random ordering (optionally with a seed)

I would consider any order dependence to be a bug - the random ordering option is there to flush out such bugs.

Comment: `file system ordering` would depend on the operating system, so if I want to run in the following order :-

2_spec.rb >
3_spec.rb >
1_spec.rb
Is this possible ?

Comment: And is there any way to make this ordering custom, as it says 
```--order option to tell RSpec how to order the files```

Comment: The orderings I described are the ones that are implemented. I don't know how difficult it would be to modify rspec to allow custom ordering

Comment: The link here https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-9/docs/command-line/order-new-in-rspec-core-2-8
says that it ```--order``` says that it provides option for ordering files...
I wonder if we can get an answer with an implementation example...

Comment: It also goes on to say that the available options are "default and rand"

Comment: Then I think random order will help us ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89808/discussion-between-nishutosh-sharma-and-frederick-cheung).