# How to execute all contexts in the defined order in RSPEC

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

My _spec structure is something as mentioned below

> describe do
>
> context do
>
> end
>
> context do
>
> end
>
> end

How I can ensure that the order of execution of all context will be as I have defined it? Currently all these executes in the random manner. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run RSpec tasks in a specific order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321166/run-rspec-tasks-in-a-specific-order)

Comment: @fabersky, Nope. My question is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rspec` will execute tests *within a spec file* in the defined order if you call it as follows:

```
rspec --order defined
```

You can also tag the example group (the one you specified with `describe`) with the meta-data `order: :defined` to do the same thing.

**However**, this only works for the test within the file.  `rspec` will execute the files in alphabetical order.  This is a current restriction in the program, based on [this issue report](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/1900) where the author states: *"RSpec does not execute tests in alphabetical order. It loads spec files in alphabetical order and then runs tests in defined order or random order depending on your configuration."*

You execute each file in a single `rspec` command with a little `bash` magic, but it may or may not be worth the effort:

```
echo "file4 file3 file1 file2" |
  xargs -n1 -t bundle exec rspec --format doc --order defined
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. are you sure that without doing any other configuration and by just mentioning order with describe, all my context will execute in the sequence as I have defined it?
Because I already tried this many times. But it didn't work.

Comment: Hmmm.  Yes, I would have thought that the command line options would override any other `.rspec` or configuration parameters to the contrary.  I use the switch frequently myself, because I like my specs to generate readable documentation as part of their output and I code the order to provide the clearest descriptions to a reader.

[Documentation here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/command-line/order).

Comment: @KapilKaushik, I think I figured out our disconnect, when I found an `rspec` issue report about the order that files get executed.  I have updated my answer accordingly.  I verified that test _files_ appear to be executed alphabetically, no matter what order you specify the file names in.

Comment: for me it doesn't work, there is no change after adding the flag, order of executed tests does not match the order of defined tests.